# How to run a visual flow with screens(Flow Type : Flow) on change of record?

Tags: visual-workflow, field-update

We have a flow with screen element which involves user input in it. This flow should be executed when user changes Opportunity stage to ‘Closed Won’ or ‘Closed Lost’.
We don't want to use custom button here instead we have to call the flow when we change the field value.

Is there a way where we can launch flows on field change?
If not please suggest other options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a flow that has interactive elements *during* the change to a record. You can either do so *before*, by using the custom button you don't want to use, or *after*, by using an embedded Visualforce page on the page layout, perhaps by way of changing the layout using a record type. However, at that point, the data will already be committed and the user could simply abort the flow and not complete the required process. Personally, I'd go with the custom button if it is absolutely critical that the flow run while changing the status.

Comment: In this Case I would prefer Custom Button Option.Thanks for the suggestion need to convince client accordingly ;)